# Send email based on form input

Tags: google-apps-script

Im looking for a google apps script that can send email based on form input.
I tried this but this is not working:

````
  for(var i in mailCreator){
      if(mailCreator[i][0].match("...@abc.nl")!=null){
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "123@def.com",
        subject: ADDED_TO_GROUP_SUBJECT,
        htmlBody: emailBody,
        })
      } 
     }```


It would be great if i can search for a certain value in the form input instead of an exact match.
````

Comment: You could accomplish this sort of thing with clientside javascript and then  pass your data to the server with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).  The use of the google-apps-script tag assume you are using the code documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) Please read that documentation to make sure that your questions conform to the needs of this forum.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is mailCreator? Is it an array where is the range with the mails? or Or try to capture a field from the form?
EDIT.

Hi Johan, I think this is better for what you need. I understand that your objetive is to send an email with the data collected from the form. I use this.

This takes the range of the form sheet and sends you an email with the data of the defined variables. We can return more data from the range obtained from the form sheet.

````
function SendMail() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var listamail = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("name sheet");

  var dataRange = listamail.getDataRange();
  
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var text = 'Text for body.'; 
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    (function(val) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[1]; //position of email header — 1
      var name = row[0]; // position of name header — 1
      var message = text ;
      var subject = 'Write subjet or ne';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      })(i);
   }
}```

You can call this function whenever you submit the form. But u need edit this and only use last value of range.
````

Comment: This dropped from my post i guess. But mailCreator is a var mailCreator = formValues['E-mailadres'][0].trim();. When a user does a form submbit his/her email address is saved in the column E-mailadres.

Comment: Thanks Antonio, i managed to get it working now. The mails are now send to the person who submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

````
var ADDED_TO_GROUP_DOC_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/location of your document';

function onFormSubmit(e) {
var mailCreator = formValues['E-mailadres'][0].trim();
var subject = 'Subject title';
var addedToGroupDocId = DocumentApp.openByUrl(ADDED_TO_GROUP_DOC_URL).getId();
var emailBody = docToHtml(addedToGroupDocId);
MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: mailCreator, 
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: emailBody,
        });
}```
````